# deploy a ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm trying to deploy a ruby on rails application.  It uses mysql for
a database.  What I would like to do is distribute it as a windows
executable.  It should be in such a way that the user can click on the
application and everything will load and a full screen browser window
will appear.  This way the user will know nothing about it being a
browser and need no ruby components installed to run the application.

i am using 3.2.6 , ruby 1.9.3 , gem 1.8.24 
Has anyone done anything like this?

Comment: Why are you using Ruby on Rails if you're developing a Windows app? Sounds like the wrong tool for the job, based on what you've posted.

Comment: @jmdeldin: you know how they say: "When you desperately need a screwdriver, even pliers will do" :)

Comment: Interesting requirement. Seems like you are going to provide a installer of your rails application. I am really interested to know how you solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a job for JRuby.

Try installing JRuby on your development machine and seeing whether your app runs in JRuby without any compatibility issues.  These days that's reasonably likely.

Running your app in JRuby gives you the ability to package up all of Ruby, Rails, your gems and your application as a single .war file which can then be deployed within a java application server like Tomcat (using tools like [warbler](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/))

This still leaves you with the task of installing all the infrastructure (database, java, java application server etc).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can create a portable distribution - self-extracting archive that will extract your Rails application, pre-configured Ruby package with all necessary gems, and a bat-file, that will add Ruby to PATH variable, run Rails server and open browser window. Making a MySQL portable will definitely be a pain in the ass, I presume.

One of the key disadvantages is almost zero level compatibility - some gems will not work on certain systems, incompatible database drivers etc.

I once tried to do the same thing with Apache+MySQL+PHP, ended up using one shared PC as a server, distributing just browser launcher as a standalone app.

Answer (score 0):

I'ld try to prepackage a virtual linux box with all what your application needs and release that instead.

And, yes, I am very interested in the final answer as well :-)